# passing a string with spaces to an -exec sh within a grep bash function

Tags: string, bash, function, pdftotext

I'm wanting to recursively search for strings in pdf files using pdftotext (not pdfgrep) using a bash function and passing my string of choice to it.  The string must be able to handle special characters, as a minimum,  spaces.     As a bare command line, this works perfectly in a bash shell and demonstrates what I want to do.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "Air France"' \; 2>/dev/null
```

But if I put the following code inside a bash shell function, I cannot get it to work.

```
function pdfsearch () { find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color  '$1' ' \;  2>/dev/null }
```

I am invoking as

```
pdfsearch 'Air France'   and also trying pdfsearch "Air France"
```

which just gives pdfs containing "Air" but not "Air France"

I also tried using $@ and also shopt -s extglob variations etc etc.    Grateful for assistance where I am going wrong.

Comment: The `pdfsearch` function you have provided is broken. Did you type it in wrong?

Comment: @jhnc  the function I typed, sits in my .bash_aliases file.   Apart from putting some blank lines between the {} it appears identical to what I have (was a copy and paste from emacs buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'$1'` part should be changed to `"'"$1"'"` (`"`, `'`, `"$1"`, `'`, `"`), if your search string is double quotes friendly.

See the following simplified example:

```
[STEP 101] # cat file.txt
hello
world
hello world
[STEP 102] # foo() { find -name file.txt -exec sh -c 'cat "{}" | grep '$1' ' \; ; }
[STEP 103] # foo 'hello world'
hello
hello world
[STEP 104] #
[STEP 105] # foo() { find -name file.txt -exec sh -c 'cat "{}" | grep "'"$1"'" ' \; ; }
[STEP 106] # foo 'hello world'
hello world
[STEP 107] #
```

Comment: The `;` you have added before the trailing `}` is important too, otherwise the shell will treat the `}` as a parameter of `find`; The function given in the question is unterminated as shown.